# Cannot move query outside of FOR loop?

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, class, for

**REQUIREMENT**: Need to move the query outside of the FOR loop in Opportunity trigger.

**PROBLEM**: After moving query outside of the FOR loop, I receive an error when trying to save a new Opportunity record (when it is triggered).

**Original Code (no issues):**

```
trigger myTrigger on Opportunity (before insert) {

    Set<Id> parentAccountIds = new Set<Id>();

    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
        parentAccountIds.add(opp.AccountId);

        //query fields on parent accounts and map them by Account Id
        Map<Id, Account> parentAccountsById = new Map<Id, Account>([
            select Id, CustomField__c
            from Account
            where Id in :parentAccountIds
        ]);

        if(String.isNotBlank(opp.AccountId)) {

            Date CustomField = parentAccountsById.get(opp.AccountId).CustomField__c;

            // do stuff

        }
    }
}
```

**Code after moving the query, has error (see below):**

```
trigger myTrigger on Opportunity (before insert) {

    Set<Id> parentAccountIds = new Set<Id>();

    //query fields on parent accounts and map them by Account Id
    Map<Id, Account> parentAccountsById = new Map<Id, Account>([
        select Id, CustomField__c
        from Account
        where Id in :parentAccountIds
    ]);

    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {

        parentAccountIds.add(opp.AccountId);

        if(String.isNotBlank(opp.AccountId)) {
            Date CustomField = parentAccountsById.get(opp.AccountId).CustomField__c;

            // do stuff

        }
    }
}
```

**ERROR:**

> myTrigger: execution of BeforeInsert caused by:
>   System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   Trigger.myTrigger: line 22, column 1

**LINE 22 refers TO:**

```
Date CustomField = parentAccountsById.get(opp.AccountId).CustomField__c;
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer by the OP does solve the problem, but I'd like to go into more detail about *why* it works (and why the initial attempt didn't work).

Let's take the bottom-most loop over `Trigger.new`

```
for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {

    if(String.isNotBlank(opp.AccountId)) {
        Date CustomField = parentAccountsById.get(opp.AccountId).CustomField__c;

        // do stuff

    }
}
```

The `if` statement ensures that our `Opportunity` does indeed have an `AccountId`, but we can still run into a Null Pointer Exception (NPE).
Without performing some sort of null check on the map (or result), `parentAccountsById.get(opp.AccountId)` can return `null`.

`null.<anything>` results in an NPE, because `null` has no properties, variables, or methods.

Looking at OP's full first attempt (with my own comments):

```
trigger myTrigger on Opportunity (before insert) {

    // This line both declares and initializes parentAccountIds
    // This allows us to use the standard set methods, but the set is empty
    Set<Id> parentAccountIds = new Set<Id>();

    // In this query, we haven't put anything into parentAccountIds
    // This query will thus return 0 rows, but still give us our initialization
    //   for the map parentAccountsById.
    // We can call any standard method of the Map class, but the map will contain nothing
    Map<Id, Account> parentAccountsById = new Map<Id, Account>([
        select Id, CustomField__c
        from Account
        where Id in :parentAccountIds
    ]);

    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {

        // We're adding accountIds to the parentAccountIds set _after_ running
        //   the query
        parentAccountIds.add(opp.AccountId);

        if(String.isNotBlank(opp.AccountId)) {
            // The opp's AccountId is not blank, but because we have nothing in
            //   parentAccountsById, we end up trying to call null.CustomField__c
            //  which results in an NPE
            Date CustomField = parentAccountsById.get(opp.AccountId).CustomField__c;

            // do stuff

        }
    }
}
```

The solution, as illustrated by paulK, is to use the following pattern:

1. Declare/initialize a collection
2. Iterate over `Trigger.new`, and add the Ids to the collection
3. Perform a query, using the collection of Ids gathered previously
4. Iterate over `Trigger.new` again, this time doing the work you want to actually do

Again, the key part of this pattern is that we iterate *twice* over `Trigger.new`. We need to gather the Ids we want to use in the query before we execute the query.

Comment: Nice explanation, Derek! Have an upvote!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the solution...

```
trigger myTrigger on Opportunity (before insert) {

    Set<Id> parentAccountIds = new Set<Id>();

    for(Opportunity newOpp : Trigger.new) {
        parentAccountIds.add(newOpp.AccountId);
    }

    //query fields on parent accounts and map them by Account Id
    Map<Id, Account> parentAccountsById = new Map<Id, Account>([
        select Id, CustomField__c
        from Account
        where Id in :parentAccountIds
    ]);

    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {

        if(String.isNotBlank(opp.AccountId)) {
            Date CustomField = parentAccountsById.get(opp.AccountId).CustomField__c;

            // do stuff

        }
    }
}
```